# URL not accessible by docker via WSL

Tags: php, docker, symfony, networking

I have a **Symfony PHP** script that accesses an external URL to get some **JSON** data but it is not reachable by the PHP and is giving an HTTP 500 Internal Server Error when tries to call it:

```
Idle timeout reached for "http://mydomain1.com/somedata".
```

My `docker-compose.yaml` file's **extra_hosts** section looks smth like this:

```
extra_hosts:
  - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
  - "mydomain1.com:some.ip.num.ber1"
  - "mydomain2.com:some.ip.num.ber2"
  - "mydomain3.com:some.ip.num.ber3"
```

Also after checking the `/etc/hosts` file I can see that docker has added the `IP/address` pairs correctly.

What could be the problem?

Comment: What OS are you running docker on? And where dies mydomain1.com point to? Local network?

Comment: @Stepan on Windows WSL and no it points to a dedicated ip outside local network